# How can I solve this collision detection bug?

Tags: java

In this code i'm trying to make collision detection between the Enemy (that is constantly moving)and the Player. I set so that the Enemy will go in the oposite direction when hit. But when the two hit each other from different directions, there is a bug: the Enemy gets stuck in the Player until I move him. I know that instead of moving in the oppoite direction, I should change so it goes away from the Player, but I don't know how. Please help me!

```
public Enemy(float x, float y, ID id, Handler handler) {
    super(x, y, id);
    this.handler = handler;
    vely = -6;
    velx = -6;
}


protected void tick(LinkedList<Object> object) {
    x += velx;
    y += vely;
    if(x <= 0){
        if(velx < 0) velx = velx * -1;
    }
    if(y <= 0) {
        if(vely < 0) vely = vely * -1;
    }
    if(x >= 605){
        if(velx > 0) velx = velx * -1;
    }
    if(y >= 418) {
        if(vely > 0) vely = vely * -1;
    }

    collision();    
}

private void collision() {
    for(int i = 0; i < handler.object.size(); i++) {
        Object obj = handler.object.get(i);
        if(obj.getId()== id.Player) {
            if(getBound().intersects(obj.getBound())) {
                velx = velx * -1;
                vely = vely * -1;
            }
        }
    }
}


protected void render(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillOval((int)x, (int)y, 30, 30);
}
public Rectangle getBound() {
    return new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, 30, 30);
}
```

Comment: You need to re-think your logic. The intersection is not a single-point event, but might persist for two or more ticks of your game loop, and your logic must account for that.

Comment: One such way to prevent this is to *resolve* the collision, e.g. by pushing the objects apart so that they don't overlap.

Comment: You should detect the point in time where the intersection occurs, not the frame where it already has occurred. In other words, you need to calculate how far you can move the enemy in its direction until it hits something, then take action, and then do the rest of the tick.

Comment: Is there a specific methos/function that can help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If the enemy is to the left of the player, set the enemy’s `velx` to negative, otherwise positive.  Similarly for `vely` if enemy is above the player.

```
// on collision...
velx = Math.abs(velx);
vely = Math.abs(vely);
if ( enemy_left_of_player() )
    velx = -velx;
if ( enemy_above_player() )
    vely = -vely;
```

Exact left/above logic will depend on size of player (is it also 30 pixels?)

Comment: Is there a difference between this code and what I did? Cause they appear to be the same...

Comment: On collision, your code reverses the enemy's direction with `velx = -velx; vely = -vely;`.  If, on the next tick, the enemy is still "colliding" with the player, it repeats `velx = -velx; vely = -vely;` which causes the enemy to revert back to its original direction, which is back towards the player, and the collision will stick until the player moves away.  With the above code, the enemy will set its direction away from the player, even if collisions persist for multiple ticks.